# How to call solana anchor smart contracts from microsoft .net code?

Tags: asp.net, .net, solana, anchor-solana

is it possible to call solana anchor smart contracts from microsoft .net code?
I see that anchor generates a IDL but it is javascript based, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of Solana's features in this library are implemented for .NET, and there are many examples with it.
https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet